# Trying to get my head around the "For exists" rule in predicate logic.

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, natural-deduction

[PREDICATE LOGIC EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cG3nY.png)I cant embed images but I've tried to link it if you can see it but if not then ill type part of the proof here:

1. p(x) ^ r(x,y)
2. r(x,y)
3. Ǝy.r(x,y)

so from line 1 to 2, we used the OR elimination right rule
and then from line 2 to 3 we use the "exists introduction" rule - [IMAGE OF EXISTS INTRODUCTION RULE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nu5IO.png)
However the condition of that rule is that "the free variable (t) must not clash with the bound variable of P". so my question is doesn't the introducing Ǝy make the y in r(x,y) clash?

Comment: Please do MathJax formatting here. Also avoid posting images of text as part of question.

Comment: Here's a link to [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) formatting.

Comment: "from line 1 to 2, we used the AND elimination rule"

Comment: It must be: "free variables occurring in term $t$ (if any) must not clash with bound variables of P". Having said that, in $r(x,y)$ there are no bound variables.

Comment: The gist of the rule is: "from $(1 > 0)$, derive $\exists x (x > 0)$. We have that: $P(x)$ is $(x > 0)$ and $t$ is $1$ and thus $P[x / t]$ is $(1 > 0)$.